# Replace a sum with an integral $\sum\rightarrow \int$

Tags: integration, summation, quantum-field-theory

How can one turn a sum to an integral. Example

$$\sum_k f(k) \approx N\cdot\int_k dk\, f(k). $$
How do you find the factor $N$?

The quantities should be approximately equal.

Example form Peskin and Schroeder page $374$:

> $$\tag{11.71}\mathrm{Tr} \log (\partial^2+m^2) = \sum_k \log(-k^2+m^2) = >(VT)\cdot\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\log(-k^2+m^2),$$
>
> where $VT$ is the four-dimensional volume of the functional integral.

Why does this $VT$ show up in equation $(11.71)$?

Comment: What does the arrow mean?

Comment: Do you want the quantities to be equal? Are you familiar with measure theory?

Comment: I updated the question slightly. I'm not very familiar with measure theory (not taken any formal course).

Comment: Look at Riemann sums. $\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n f(\frac{k}{n+1})$ converges to $\int_0^1 f(k) dk$ (in good cases, but since this is a physics question it doesn't really matter).

Comment: To avoid more confusion you should add more details to the question (or maybe move it to Physics SE). Important things here: 1) $k$ here is the Fourier-space wave-number. 2) The method used by the authors is: discretize the space (and thereby Fourier space), solve equations etc. (this gives you sums), consider the large $n$ limit to get from sums to the integral you are interested in. 3) The integrals are implicitly assumed to be only over wavelengths availiable to us from the discretization. All these things are needed to properly answer the question in the context given here.

Comment: Crossposted to: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143467/2451

Comment: @DanZimm Would this problem be solved in a more efficient and natural way using measure theory?

Comment: @MusséRedi I'm a bit out of practice right now - but I think I was along the line of thought that you could try to use the counting measure to transition between the two forms. However in hindsight I see that this was bad advice because you're trying to actually calculate $N$. Sorry for the mis-advice

Comment: @DanZimm Okay! Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a physics question (or at least the context is) so be warned: non-rigorous explanations to follow.

For 1D. Take a (real space) box with volume $V = L$ and discretize it on a lattice using $n$ points. This gives rise to following Fourier space lattice: $k = \frac{i}{n}k_{\rm max}$ for $i=-n,\ldots,n$ where $k_{\rm max} = \frac{2\pi n}{L}$. This is the setup of the problem.

To find $N$ s.t.

$$\sum_k \approx N \int dk$$

we first note that

$$\sum_k = 2n$$

is the number of $k$ modes that we can fit onto our lattice. Further we have (note that the integral here is to be interpreted as the integral over the modes we have availiable so we only integrate over $[-k_{\rm max},k_{\rm max}]$)

$$\int dk = 2k_{\rm max}$$

so

$$N = \frac{n}{k_{\rm max}} = \frac{V}{2\pi}$$

This was for 1D, but the procedure above can be done for the general case giving

$$N = \frac{V_{4D}}{(2\pi)^4} = \frac{V T}{(2\pi)^4}$$

Comment: Is it correct if one uses the mnemonic: normalize the sum such that $$1:=\sum_{k_x}=N_x\underbrace{\int dk_x}_{\text{volume of ball of allowed }k-values=\frac{2\pi}{L_x}}\Rightarrow N_x = \frac{L_x}{2\pi}.$$ Generalizing to four dimension gives the result.

Comment: @Winther, could you please also explain what $N_x$ should be for the case of the box being of size $L$, while momenta belonging to the interval ${(0,+\infty)}$? (This happens when quantising a relativistic theory on the light cone.)

Answer (score 1):

Define a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ by $\mu(A)=|A\cap\mathbb Z|$.

Then $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}f(k)=\int f\operatorname{d}\mu$.

This way a sum is turned into an integral.

Comment: How do you define that measure and is the equal sign really an equal sign?

Comment: I describe in my answer how you define the measure: $\mu(A)=|A\cap\mathbb Z|$ i.e. the number of integers $n$ that satisfy $n\in A$. Equal signs are equal signs just the way as apples are apples.

Comment: Thanks @drhab, good to know that. I have updated the question to be more specific. Could you have a look please?

Comment: Rely on the answer of @Did. I am leaving now. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is nonincreasing, $$\int_0^{n}f(x)\,\mathrm dx+f(n)-f(0)\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)\leqslant\int_0^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$If $f$ is nondecreasing, $$\int_0^{n}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)\leqslant\int_0^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx+f(n)-f(0).$$ No prefactor $N$ in sight...